# Entity Framework and MVC: generating CONTROLLER code from entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, json.net, odata

I'm on an assignment to to expose SQL data using MVC via OData.
I'm working with an existing project, Visual Studio 2015.
A bunch of tables have already been exposed.

Please first accept my apologies for perhaps a poorly crafted post.
I'm having a hard time figuring out what I'm actually working with.
In addition, I've had only a day to familiarize myself with this project.

I know that I said MVC but as far as I can tell, this project does not have VIEWS.  I do believe however that the consumers of this project will read JSON.

I've used the Entity Framework to build the MODEL for the additional tables required to finish my assignment.

I'm working now on the CONTROLLER code, and I'd like to use a tool to automate that portion as much as possible.  Below please find an example of a CONTROLLER already defined.  I include that to help you get a feel for the type of tool I'm looking for.

Does such a tool exist?  Or do I have to notepad a CONTROLLER for the tables that I've added to the project?

Thank you kindly for reading my post and for any assistance you can offer :)

```
public class BlockController : ODataController
{
    AccordNewModel _db = new AccordNewModel();

    [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(_db.Block.AsQueryable());
    }

    [ODataRoute()]
    [HttpPost]
    [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Block newBlock)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        _db.Block.Add(newBlock);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return Created(newBlock);
    }

    [ODataRoute()]
    [HttpPut]
    [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
    public IHttpActionResult Put(Block block)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        _db.Block.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.BlockID }, block);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return Updated(block);
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public IHttpActionResult Delete([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        var block = _db.Block.SingleOrDefault(t => t.BlockID == key);
        _db.Block.Remove(block);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return Content(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "Deleted");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: With your information, i understand that its web-api you are trying to mention. What kind of tool you want? What you want to automate?

Answer (score 0):

It makes little sense to write very similar controller code multiple times, I would advise against generating 1 controller per entity. Instead you could use a generic solution:

```
public class BaseController<T> : ODataController
{
    AccordNewModel _db = new AccordNewModel();

    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(_db.Set<T>().AsQueryable());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(T posted)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        var added = _db.Set<T>().Add(posted);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return Created(added);
    }

    //Etc... Write generic controller methods using Db.Set<T>()
```

Then for every entity you need not do much, here is how your 'block' entity controller would look:

```
public class BlockController : BaseController<Block> { }
```

For delete and update you need some way to identify the generic object of `T` by Id (`int key`). I know of two ways to do this:

**1:** Let your entities implement an interface `IHasId` which ensures they have an `int Id` property, then add a generic constraint to the `BaseController` class like so: `public class BaseController<T> : ODataController where T : IHasId`. Delete method could look like this:

```
[HttpDelete]
public IHttpActionResult Delete([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    var found = _db.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == key);
    if(found != null)
    {
        _db.Set<T>().Remove(found);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return StatusCode(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Or, **2:** Make the BaseController class abstract and add: `protected abstract T GetById(int id);`. Then inheriting classes (such as 'BlockController') must implement a method to get the object from the Db by id. You will have to implement this method for every entity, this is still less work than writing individual controllers for every entity. The delete method would look almost the same as the one above except: `var found = GetById(key);`.

I use `Delete` as an example, but if you have some way to get an entity by id you can quite easily implement the `Post` and possibly a `Get(int key)` as well.

With this generic base class the code per entity is minimal and writing it for every entity shouldn't be too much work.

Comment: Hey @flaZer, this getting you anywhere? Or have you found another solution?

Comment: yeah I've made progress and it was as easy as right-clicking within project explorer, and adding a controller where VS wrote each controller for me. So that automated tool for me was hiding in plain sight.  I do however find value in your approach but still haven't consumed it - a lot of pressure here at work.